# Domain Of definition of the function $y = ([x] + x^2 -1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The quantity under the principal root should be non-negative so,

$$[x] + x^2 -1 \geq 0$$

That is,

$$[x] \geq 1 - x^2$$

This inequality can easily be solved by plotting graphs of both LHS and RHS and then comparing the heights in different intervals giving the answer as $x \leq -\sqrt{3}$ or $x \geq 1$

Is there any analytical way to solve this question, i.e by just using pure algebra?
I gave it a try as follows:

Let $[x] = n$ and ${x} = f$ (fractional part function)

So, $x = n + f$

And the inequality becomes
$f^2 + 2nf + n^2 - n + 1 \geq 0$

How do I proceed from here, knowing that fractional part $x$ belongs to $[0,1)$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $(-\infty, -\sqrt 3) \cup [1,\infty)$.
First note that if $x < -2$ then $-n-1\leq x<-n$ with $ n \geq 2$. Hence $[x]+x^{2}-1=x^{2}-n-2\geq n^{2}-n-2\geq 0$. [$n(n-1)-2 \geq (2)(1)-2 \geq 0$].

If $x \geq 1$ then $[x]+x^{2}-1 \geq [x]-1 \geq 0$. Now you are left with $x \in [-2,-1) \cup [-1,0)\cup [0,1)$. I will let you handle these three intervals.

Comment: I guess you have a typo with the brackets in the very first line.

Comment: @VIVID If you are thinking that  I should remove  $-2$ from the first interval you can check that $-2$ is a valid point in the domain.

Comment: When taking a union one could say $-2)\cup[2$ or just concatenate the two intervals since they are joint.

Comment: @VIVID You are right. Thanks for the comment.